# How to modify replication factor of a topic using Java API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'd like to modify a replication factor of Kafka topic. I tried looking into AdminClient but found no suitable method.

I don't want to use any cli/ui utility for that, I want to use java.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's a piece of configuration called `transaction.state.log.replication.factor`. I also found some examples of the configuration that affects it in use on GitHub in case those are helpful.


https://github.com/search?l=Java%20Properties&q=transaction.state.log.replication.factor&type=Code

Comment: @LuciaCerchie Transactions are not what the question is asking about

Answer (score 1):

> don't want to use any cli/ui utility for that, I want to use java

`kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` **is a wrapper around (compiled) Java**. You can look at the source code for how it works, but this is the only way to increase replication factor since you must manually determine where to place the replicas.